# Batching external call to external service in cloudflare worker

Tags: amazon-kinesis-firehose, cloudflare-workers

I am working on a small worker that logs to an external service (Kinesis firehose) and then does a redirect

I am trying to batch the external calls together to avoid hitting ingestion limits. Is this the correct way to do it or is there a better way? (p.s i looked at using queues but the cost would be high for what we need)

It seems to work locally but not when deployed

Thank you

Josh

```
import { createUrl, getFinalUrl, getUserId, isValidUrl } from "./lib/url";
import { sendToFirehose } from "./lib/sendToFirehose";

export interface Env {
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: string;
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: string;
}

let batch: Record<any, any>[] = [];
export default {
  async fetch(request: Request, env: Env): Promise<Response> {
    const { pathname, searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
    ////
    
    const data = {
      date: new Date(),
      url: request.url,  
    };

    batch.push(data);

    if (batch.length === 100) {
      console.log("Batch size reached, sending to firehose");
      await sendToFirehose(batch);
      batch = [];
    }

    return Response.redirect("http://newurl.com", 302);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the best way to do it is using cloudflare queue feature

Comment: To add to this, accumulating a batch in a global variable won't work well because when you deploy your Worker, many different instances of your worker will run all over the world. They will be started on-demand and shut down if there is no more traffic in the given location. Each instance would end up having its own batch, and when shut down if the batch was non-empty it would be lost. Using Workers Queues is probably a good solution here.